# Ember.js, Rails and Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: ruby, ember.js, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-router

How can I use ember.js routing with rails wildcard subdomains?

Say, a user signs up on the site, they get a subdomain. Joe and Josh both sign up, they each get a subdomain.

`joe.mysite.com`
`josh.mysite.com`

Rails routes all my api calls (routes.rb) while ember routes everything else. What would the best way of doing this? Using rails or ember to route it? Is it even possible to use ember to route subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be programmatically checking with `location.host` or `location.hostname`.

But ember usually works it's magic by faking URLs and not reloading the page... I don't know of any way to switch subdomains without reloading the page.

I'd redirect the subdomain to a URL in your main app and let Ember handle the routing from there.